# java 3d object position

Tags: java, position, java-3d

i have little problem with object positioning in java 3d engine.
I trying to place my 3d model in center of coordinate using the center of the object on basis of its. That mean, that center of object is located at the base of the object, but not in the middle of its height, as is done in java3d. 
Here is how java3d doing it: ...
I haven't reputation 10... I can post only 2 urls... So there is url [horizont view](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r0zghzog8yli88y/XmYbqUnA9J#f%3aoutput_CHECK_center_look.png)
And there what i need to be: ...
[object placed in 0,0,0 by the center of it's base](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r0zghzog8yli88y/XmYbqUnA9J#f%3aoutput_CHECK_center_look_good.png)

***How can i do this?***

I uses this code:

```
 TransformGroup tg = this.olib.get_model(model); // Taking my model from lib
 Transform3D transform = new Transform3D();
//p.x =0; p.y=0; p.z=0; (center)
 Vector3d vector = new Vector3d(p.x, p.y, p.z); // p is a class x,y,z,yAxis(rotation), scale
 transform.setScale(p.scale);
 Transform3D rotate1 = new Transform3D();
 rotate1.rotY(p.yAxis);
 transform.mul(rotate1);
 transform.setTranslation(vector);
 tg.setTransform(transform);
 objRoot.addChild(tg);
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the problem. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Sorry for my english.. I need to place 3d object above, because designed center of my object in it's base. Java think that center in the middle of height of object, because object is tall.

Comment: then probably the problem lies within your model, and not the code.
you can of course try to compensate that with a translation (linear transformation) - but I guess I would start by trying to fix the model.

Comment: Here is my model, you can see, that it placed on center of coordinate in the middle of it's base: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r0zghzog8yli88y/Boc5DjcGQ9/1.jpg?m

Comment: And the second view: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r0zghzog8yli88y/hcXedxKxee/2.jpg?m

Comment: Correcting targets, may be there is some methods to know size of 3d object? I could substract half height from y position...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in incorrect loader.
That's how i loaded my object to 3d Scene:

```
TransformGroup obj = new TransformGroup();
Scene s = null;
ObjectFile f = new ObjectFile ();
f.setFlags (ObjectFile.RESIZE | ObjectFile.TRIANGULATE | ObjectFile.STRIPIFY);
try{ s = f.load (obj_path+model+"\\"+model+".obj"); }catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
obj.addChild(s.getSceneGroup());
obj.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
```

The problem is in that row:

```
f.setFlags (ObjectFile.RESIZE | ObjectFile.TRIANGULATE | ObjectFile.STRIPIFY);
```

Flag ObjectFile.RESIZE mean that object loaded from file placed in the middle of it's height to the center of coordinate and decrease or increase size of object from it's original to range x:[-1,1]; y:[-1,1]; z:[-1,1].

But there no way to know current size of object, like width or height... Well, or i could not find in google.